# Just a error seems simple can not find him

Tags: android, maps

what is the error?

is wrong ?

They can not help understand

[image]

http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/error2-1006709.png

Comment: If you hover over the red cross mark, it'll tell you the error. Can you post that ?

Comment: yes Taxi\res\values\styles.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace the current parent value with : `"android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`

You're just using `"android:Theme.Holo.Light"` which is incorrect.

Comment: o.O Why the downvote ?

Comment: will not you help a friend is giving me errors